# What acids will Sodium Lauroyl Methyl Isethionate yield after hydrolysis?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, hydrolysis

As far as I understand, after hydrolysis Sodium Lauroyl Methyl Isethionate will yield sodium, lauroyl and methyl alcohols, and isethionic acid. Meaning lauroyl is referring to the fatty acid alcohol rather than to the acid itsIf.

But I have read that this is compound is defined as "the sodium salt of the methyl lauric acid ester of isethionic acid", which sounds like it would actually yield lauric acid rather than the alcohol.

So which is it? Will it yield lauric acid after hydrolysis or lauroyl alcohol? And how can I tell based off the name?

I think I may be mixed up in my understanding of salts versus esters, since I definitely have more experience with the latter. Most of the information I have found on the nomenclature of salts is not comprehensive enough to discuss complex salts such as this one. If you are aware of such a reference, please share.

Comment: Isethionates are esters of long-chain aliphatic carboxylic acids ($\ce{C8-C18}$) with isethionic acid (2-hydroxyethanesulfonic acid) or salts thereof, such as ammonium isethionate or sodium isethionate ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isethionates)). Therefore, hydrolysis of any of them may yields more than one acid.

Comment: Is there any way to tell based on the name which acids might be yielded?

Comment: Since you said it is a Sodium Lauroyl derivative, it is already a salt of isethionaic acid (sulfonate). Upon hydrolysis, it release hydroxy terminal of isethionate. So, you got salts of both acids (assuming base hydrolysis).

Comment: Laur**o**yl not lauryl - it's acyl not alkyl.